# Save to XML File Does not Save - WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, app-config

When I go to save to my XML File, all the correct values are inputed and my code appears to run smoothly, with the correct **App.config value** being saved to the correct **App.config key**, however when I go to save to my XML file it does not work.

My Code is here

**App.config:**

```
<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="Test" value="Entry"/>
<add key="Directory" value="WYNW"/>
</appSettings>
<*More stuff*>
```

**What I used to call my save**

```
private void btnDirectory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string oldDirectory = btnDirectory.Content.ToString();
    string newDirectory = grabFolder();  //Grab Folder just grabs the folder location as a string
    if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newDirectory)))
    {
        btnDirectory.Content = newDirectory;
        changeValue(KeyValue[1], oldDirectory, newDirectory); //KeyValue[1] is "Directory"
    }
}
```

**What I used to save to XML**

```
public void changeValue(string Key_Value, string Old_Value, string New_Value)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Change " + Old_Value + " to " + New_Value + " for " + Key_Value, "Sales Vault Notifer", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
            {
                XmlDocument XMLdoc = new XmlDocument();
                XMLdoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
                foreach (XmlElement element in XMLdoc.DocumentElement)
                {
                    if (element.Name == "appSettings")
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode node in element.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            if (node.Attributes[0].Value == Key_Value)
                            {
                                node.Attributes[1].Value = New_Value;
                                MessageBox.Show(node.Attributes[1].Value); //Check to make sure that correct key-value has been changed ... It shows that it changes to what directory I want
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                XMLdoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Everything works smoothly until I get to the XMLdoc.Save() part. I used this code in a C# application and it worked smoothly but when I switched to WPF the Yes/No part of MessageBoxes was different and required(from what I could find) as switch to check, so I assume that the *break;* is the reason I cannot save.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers, 
iato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I came to the conclusion that:

The document was being saved, just it was been saved to

*//MyProject/bin/debugg/MyProject.exe.config*

instead of where I was editing manually my config file of

*//MyProject/App.config*

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10105349/5116032) by **slugster**

Thus when I go to open my App.config file in Visual Studio, no changes have been made, however when I go to read from my config file,

```
using System.Configuration;
var Variable = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Directory");
```

the correct changes have been made.

Hopefully this helps whoever had the same issue I had :)